# How to Replace Integer Boolean Value With A String Value Inside Loop

Tags: php, sql, csv, mysqli, export-to-csv

I just made a csv export feature for my application but I am stuck on one feature I would like to implement. In my database, my 'active' column holds a value of 0 or 1 (obviously 0 being false and 1 being true). When the results come back, I would like to replace those values with either "Active" or "Inactive", based of the number boolean stored in the database, when my csv is generated. The code below is what I have. I am successfully exporting a csv, again, I just don't know how to replace those integer booleans with a string.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=new.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'active', 'role', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username', 'datecreated'));
$results = mysqli_query($database->connection, "SELECT id, active, role, firstname, lastname, email, username, date_created FROM users");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)):
 // I know I need to do something here to replace those values
 fputcsv($output, $result);
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple check with if/else

```
if($result['active'] == 1){ 
    $result['active'] = 'Active' 
} else { 
    $result['active'] = 'Inactive' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)):
    $row = $result;
    $row['active'] = $row['active'] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';

    fputcsv($output, $row);
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to apply this logic in the MySQL query itself, using the `IF` clause.

```
SELECT id, IF(active = 1, 'Active', 'Inactive'), role, 
firstname, lastname, email, username, date_created 
FROM users
```

Will give you directly what you are after without having to loop over the results from the select and modify them.